# Running into reccurring errors when trying to implement socket.io into my application using Node w/ Express

Tags: html, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

So, I've been trying to implement textbox where multiple people can type at once. This is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>wecode.collaboration()</title>
        ...
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="coding.css" />
        <script src="/node_modules/socket.io/client-dist/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script defer src="/webpages/codingspace/codinglogic.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <div class="content">
            <textarea id="codingSpace" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the accompanying client-side code. `codinglogic.js`:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const socket = io();

    const codingSpace = document.getElementById("codingSpace");

    // Listen for code changes from the server and update the text area
    socket.on("codeChange", (newCode) => {
        codingSpace.value = newCode;
    });

    // Listen for user input and send code changes to the server
    codingSpace.addEventListener("input", () => {
        const newCode = codingSpace.value;
        socket.emit("codeChange", newCode);
    });
});
```

and this is the server side code `server.js`:

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server);
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/webpages/codingspace"));
app.use(
    "/socket.io",
    express.static(__dirname + "/node_modules/socket.io/client-dist")
);


app.get("/code", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/webpages/codingspace/coding.html");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
})

// WebSocket handling
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("A user connected");

    // Listen for changes from clients
    socket.on("codeChange", (newCode) => {
        // Broadcast the new code to all connected clients, including the sender
        io.emit("codeChange", newCode);
    });

    // Handle disconnection
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("A user disconnected");
    });
});
```

And now finally the error I come across:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OhRSvvL 404 (Not Found)
create @ polling.js:298
Request @ polling.js:237
request @ polling.js:190
doPoll @ polling.js:215
poll @ polling.js:96
doOpen @ polling.js:56
open @ transport.js:46
open @ socket.js:170
Socket @ socket.js:111
open @ manager.js:108
Manager @ manager.js:39
lookup @ index.js:29
(anonymous) @ codinglogic.js:2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.
Instead of

```
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
})
```

Use

```
server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
})
```